# DefaultPropertiesPersister Load from InputStream and Handle Http Error

Tags: java, spring

I am using DefaultPropertiesPersister of spring to load my properties hosted on another server in Input Stream as shown below:

```
Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource(url);
InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
propertiesPersister.load(props, new InputStreamReader(is, encoding));
```

If URL returns http error like 404-Page not found or 500-Internal Server Error, how can I handle that.

I am asking because, in case of 404 and 500 errors server will return an error page, which is convertible to InputStream, which makes it a valid input to PropertiesPersister.

I want to catch and handle http errors, kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the http provider you are using.

By default, when you open an HTTP URL as a resource, the Spring Framework use the method `URL.openConntection().getInputStream()`. The return depends on the HTTP protocol resolver that you are using in the JVM.

If you use Sun JVM or OpenJDK, the default HTTP URL handler is `sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler` that check the code returned from the server and, if the code is 404 then throws a `FileNotFoundException` and if a error 500 is returned from server, then throws a generic `IOException`.

If you want to have more control on the communication, then you can use a API to make the request more controlled like [Http Client from Apache](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)